# Knockd issues ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

So I have setup knockd on Ubuntu server which seemed to work. The issue which I am facing is that when I attempt to use the port knocking service, I receive the following errors:

```
"Start request repeated too quickly"
"Failed to start port-knock daemon"
```

If however, I run the knockd service in debug mode using the following command:

```
knockd -D -v
```

Then the knockd service works correctly. Is there any reason that the service only works in debug mode?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.